# Does the 'verb form' always have to agree with the 'subject number'?

Tags: grammaticality

Is the 'verb and subject number agreement' a hard-and-fast rule? Or is there some leeway?

For example, in the following sentences do I need to change the verb from 'was' to 'were' to match the subject number.

Change:

> All that mattered **was** his dream and the boy that would help
>   realize it.

to:

> All that mattered **were** his dream and the boy that would help
>   realize it.

---

And, change:

> The first **thing** that sprang to mind as I watched Arpan walk out of
>   the arrivals gate and look around  the airport **was** the mad fervor
>   that afflicted me about a decade ago and the boundless darkness that
>   lurked in the two mountains.

to:

> The first **things** that sprang to mind as I watched Arpan walk out
>   of the arrivals gate and look around the airport **were** the mad
>   fervor that afflicted me about a decade ago and the boundless darkness
>   that lurked in the two mountains.

or:

> What first sprang to mind as I watched him walk out of the arrivals
>   gate and look around the airport **were** the mad fervor that
>   afflicted me about a decade ago and the boundless darkness that lurked
>   in the two mountains.

In the first example, I find nothing wrong with changing 'was' to 'were' but in the second example, I'm not comfortable using 'were' for some reason.

Comment: If the rule comes from a grammar textbook, it's probably wrong anyway, so certainly there is a great deal of latitude. Or perhaps I should say there's a lot of variations. The key is to listen to the **speech**; writing is impossible to understand without hearing the sounds in one's mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, subject and verb must always agree. That said, there can be complexities and special cases.

In your first example, "was" is correct and "were" is wrong. I think you are getting confused by the word "all". In general, "all" is plural. "All the brothers were valiant." "All roads lead to Rome." Etc. It takes a plural verb.

But the phrase "all I need" is something of an idiom. It indicates the one thing or one set of things that you need, and so is treated as singular.

> All I need is this chair.

There is only one thing that I need: this chair. It's singular.

If you're identifying more than one thing, either a singular or a plural is acceptable:

> All I need is a chair and a lamp.
>
> All I need is two chairs.
>
> All I need are a chair and a lamp.
>
> All I need are two chairs.

All good.

In the second example, you are identifying two things: the fervor AND the darkness, so it is plural and the correct verb is "were".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But wrt the first example, aren't there two things that matter? His dream and the boy? So shouldn't it be 'were'?

Comment: I know they're something of a special case, but 330,000 written instances of ["there's a few"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22there%27s+a+few%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) don't seem to have subject/verb agreement.

Comment: @Soulz: As Jay's examples show, when "all you need", or "all that matters" consists of two (or maybe even more) closely-related things, it's quite normal to treat them as singular. For example, [All you need **is** a pencil and paper.](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22all+you+need+is+a+pencil+and+paper%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)